# Android. Как слушать EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

У меня есть два Фрагмента (`FirstFragment` и `SecondFragment`) и есть `EditText`, но он расположен в другом `xml` файле и я не знаю как получить доступ к нему, чтоб слушать через функцию `addTextListener` данный `editText`

```
public void addTextListener(){
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {
            searchText = query.toString();

            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            ArrayList<Event> filteredList = events;

            try {
                RealmResults<Event> filteredCities = realm.where(City.class).contains("title", searchText, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
                filteredList.clear();
                filteredList = (ArrayList<Event>) realm.copyFromRealm(filteredCities);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            } finally {
                realm.close();
            }

            mEventAdapter.updateData(filteredList);
            dataLoading = true;

            APIService.getEventsBySearch(searchText);
        }
    });
}`
```

`EditText`, который мне надо слушать, расположен в `NavigationView`, а `NavigationView` расположена в `FeedActivity`. `FeedActivity` использует `ViewPager`, чтоб отображать мои Фрагменты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**searchText** в функции `addTextListener` - это `EditText`.

**Дополнение:**

NavigationView:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@color/dark80">

            <EditText
              android:id="@+id/filter_search"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="Search..."
              android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_compat"
              android:background="@drawable/circle"
              android:theme="@style/StyleForEditText"
              android:layout_below="@+id/customize_feed"
              android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
              android:textSize="16sp"
              android:paddingTop="6dp"
              android:paddingLeft="16dp"
              android:paddingRight="8dp"
              android:paddingBottom="6dp"/> 
          </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: `searchText` в функции `addTextListener` - это **НЕ** `EditText`, это `CharSequence`
Все-таки из вашего описания не понятно, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: searchText - string, search - EditText. Мне нужно слушать этот editText, который прописан в другой XML

Comment: а что вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: у вас с ошибкой вылетает? или какая проблема?

Comment: Как именно расположено поле ввода в NavigationView? в хедере?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Выше подробно описал. Navigation View прописан в xml FeedAcivity. В самом FeedActivity есть ViewPager в котором показываются Fragments

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, вы недостаточно описали. Поле ввода в боковое меню можно добавить множеством разных способов и достучаться до него также можно по разному. Ответьте на вопрос выше. Приведите разметку с NavigationView

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Дополнил ответ!

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, ох, такого способа я не предполагал даже) Покажите ещё в вопросе как вы пытаетесь инициализировать этот EditText

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я не знаю как это делается. Я вот хотел узнать, как можно слушать данный EditText, который вообще прописан в другой XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно реализовать это с помощью интерфейса.

```
public interface OnSearchTextChanged {
    void onSearchTextChanged(String searchText());
}
```

В рамках активити нужно реализовать стандартную логику (которая приведена в вашем примере). Дальше, имплементируете этот интерфейс в фрагменте и подписываетесь на изменения у активити. Например вот так:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        try {
            ((YourActivityName) activity).setOnSearchTextChangedListener(this);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // Оставьте пустым или бросьте эксепшен
        }
    }
}
```

И дальше все изменения будете получать в реализованном методе интерфейса OnSearchTextChanged.

Не забудьте, на всякий, отписаться в методе onDetach();

**Дополнено**:

Вариант номер два - вы можете найти нужную вьюшку используя активити:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.filter_search)
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем конкретном случае никакой разницы с обычным способом действий нет. Вы через include добавили разметку и можете поступать с ней так, будто она

Вам надо просто найти View по её ID так:

```
EditText search = (EditText) findViewByid(R.id.filter_search);
```